# Trying to get index.php to load under HTML5 head bar without interputing music playback while user browse site?

Tags: php, html, joomla, navigation, html5-audio

what tag do i need to use to have joomla index.php load below my that header.

Been trying this for ever .. i am almost there.. : as you can see the player on top .. if you hit the arrow  forward key it plays .. and you can navigate the page below without playback interruption

Thank you.   ..
   ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building your site with iframe is not a good idea because url will never change.

So, you need to fully ajaxify your website using this plugin, for example (i never give it a try) : http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/site-performance/13293

Or embed your own solution with jQuery plugins, for example.